# Mysql update column = column + 1 return 0

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
update table set column = column + 1 where id = #{id}
```

why this sql could return 0 
I believe it will always return 1

Comment: `update` queries don't return anything.  You are confused.  `select` queries return result sets.

Comment: If you mean by return, that `column` got set to `0`, maybe it was `-1` before the `UPDATE`.

Comment: sorry,  i mean affected rows and that will always be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
```

If yes, then it return "0" if there is no changes in DB table by supplied statement.

In your case,

```
update table set column = column + 1 where id = #{id}
```

If your statement say's, "0" mean the parameter that you are passing for column "id" doesn't match any records in table, hence no records affected in DB table.

## Obserbation:

In your update statement you are saying "update table" without back quote, mean I guess it will return MySQL error because you have used reserved key.

Or else you could try like this:

```
update `table`
```